# How to remove the gradient of Libre Office on dark theme of KDE?

Tags: debian, kde, libreoffice

I'm using the Dark Theme of the Debian 9 with KDE Plasma 5.8.6, but when I open the Libre Office, this is what I see:
[image]
I think this gradient is very ugly, so I want to change for a solid color, or for another theme that matches with the system.

Comment: Look at Tools Options LibreOffice Personalization in the menu

Comment: I already tried that, but I didn't find the settings to change the color of the toolbar. I found the options to change the icons and menus, but not to change the color.

Comment: You can't do that. The WM is responsible for that. You can set only one theme so you must change it.

Comment: I found a way, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit funny, but the best way to fix the problem with the dark theme is just update the LibreOffice.

This is a print screen of the Writer after I updated it to the 6.0.6 version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this look better.

First, I had to install [libreoffice-breeze-icons](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libreoffice-breeze-icons) at the Libre Office and set this as the icon theme on `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View > Icon style`.

The program will be looking like this:
[image]

Then, I needed go to `Tools > LibreOffice > Options > Accessibility` and check the box *Automatically detect high contrast mode of operating system*.

Now, the program is like this:
[image]

I found the icon pack in a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4vh8zg/how_do_i_make_libreoffice_look_better_on_kde_on/) on Reddit, and this [video](https://youtu.be/gd45GC3lCSI) helped me to install it at Libre Office.

Comment: Actually, this causes a problem with the other colors of the program. I'm searching for another way to do this in the moment.